# boolean check behaving unexpectedly when returning value

Tags: c++, boolean

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

bool is_favorite(std::string word) 
{
    int isTrueCounter = 0;

    std::cout << "\nisTrueCounter: " << isTrueCounter;

    if (isTrueCounter == word.length())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            if (word[i] == 'a' || word[i] == 'A')
            {
                isTrueCounter++;
                std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
            }
            else
            {
                if (word[i] == 'b' || word[i] == 'B')
                {
                    isTrueCounter++;
                    std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (word[i] == 'c' || word[i] == 'C')
                    {
                        isTrueCounter++;
                        std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
                    }
                    else {
                        if (word[i] == 'd' || word[i] == 'D')
                        {
                            isTrueCounter++;
                            std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (word[i] == 'e' || word[i] == 'E')
                            {
                                isTrueCounter++;
                                std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (word[i] == 'f' || word[i] == 'F')
                                {
                                    isTrueCounter++;
                                    std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } //for
    }

    std::cout << "\nisTrueCounter: " << isTrueCounter;

}

int main()
{
    std::string favWord;
    std::cout << "Please input your word: ";
    std::cin >> favWord;
    std::cout << "\nFavWord Length: " << favWord.length();
    
    if (is_favorite(favWord) == true)
    {
        std::cout << "\nThis is a favorite word!";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nThis is NOT a favorite word!";
    }
}
```

Here is my code, I am attempting to pass a string into a boolean function that will return true if all criteria is met by the string passed. The qualifications for a "passing" word is that it contains ONLY the letters a-f (of either case) so words like AaAa or Cafe or Bad should pass, but after trial and error, even words that I know should pass are failing and I feel like I am keeping track of the letters' qualifications properly, by incrementing on a variable (isTrueCounter) to count if all the characters in the string are qualifying characters, but even when the function should be returning true, the false case displays. What am I doing wrong? What am I not seeing? When I run this code it will display the variables to help keep track of when stuff is being added to the holder variables but even when all the numbers are right the false case displays.

Comment: You only return true when the very first condition is true, there is no other return statement.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do this the other way around. Return false immidiately when you find something that is *not* a-f. Otherwise return true. Also, you can check for a range or characters with something like `word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'f'`.

Comment: @super I was just about to ask that exact question, I'll rearrange some things, I like that approach better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't return anything, you can do this in many way. For example from your code, `return false` immediatly after condition is not true (not in a-f).

```
bool is_favorite(std::string word) 
{
    int isTrueCounter = 0;
    std::cout << "\nisTrueCounter: " << isTrueCounter;
    if (isTrueCounter == word.length())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            if (word[i] == 'a' || word[i] == 'A')
            {
                isTrueCounter++;
                std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
            }
            else
            {
                if (word[i] == 'b' || word[i] == 'B')
                {
                    isTrueCounter++;
                    std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (word[i] == 'c' || word[i] == 'C')
                    {
                        isTrueCounter++;
                        std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
                    }
                    else {
                        if (word[i] == 'd' || word[i] == 'D')
                        {
                            isTrueCounter++;
                            std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (word[i] == 'e' || word[i] == 'E')
                            {
                                isTrueCounter++;
                                std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (word[i] == 'f' || word[i] == 'F')
                                {
                                    isTrueCounter++;
                                    std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
                                } else {         //add this else clause
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } //for
    }
    std::cout << "\nisTrueCounter: " << isTrueCounter;
}
```

But some of your code can improve.

1.I don't know why you add these lines. This will never true unless `word.length()` is 0.

```
if (isTrueCounter == word.length())
{
    return true;
}
```

2.Don't split condition that can write in one `if` into many `if`, it's a bad behavior.

```
if (word[i] == 'a' || word[i] == 'A')
{
    isTrueCounter++;
    std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
}
else
{
    if (word[i] == 'b' || word[i] == 'B')
    {
        isTrueCounter++;
        std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
    }
```

This is better.

```
if (word[i] == 'a' || word[i] == 'A' || word[i] == 'b' || word[i] == 'B')
{
    isTrueCounter++;
    std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
}
```

3.You can compare `char`, instead of check if `word[i] == 'a'...` Use `> < >= <=`.

```
if (word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'f' || word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'F')
{
    isTrueCounter++;
    std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
}
```

4.`string` is already in `iostream` you don't have to import it again.

In conclusion your code can turn into this

```
bool is_favorite(std::string word) 
{
    int isTrueCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        if (word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'f' || word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'F') {
            isTrueCounter++;
            std::cout << "\nisTrue +1 ";
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\nisTrueCounter: " << isTrueCounter;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Extremely helpful and informative, thank you for taking the time to answer with as much detail and tutelage as possible, you have very much helped me get better at programming.

Comment: In the first function above, after the very last `std::cout << ...` we should also `return` something.

Comment: Yes...I forgot that. If not return anything, it will cause error.